# Google Maps route playback

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps

I'm looking for a jquery plugin or any solution to playback (with animation) a route in a kml layer. such as.: http://ridewithgps.com/trips/337442

Answer (score 1):

Some examples here:

[API V3 driving:](http://geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html) - [API V2 driving:](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip2.htm) - [API V3 flight](http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_flight_path_animated.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to [animate a marker along a polyline](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html) (the polyline comes from the directions service)

You can load Kml specified polylines as native google.maps.Polyline objects using a third party kml parser (like [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) or [geoxml_v3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/))